# Is there any restriction in entering the South American countries multiple times in one year?

Tags: visa-free-entry, eu-citizens, brazil, repeat-visits, south-america

As an EU citizen I can travel to Brazil, Uruguay, Paraguay, and Argentina without a visa, just by using my passport.

Currently I am in Brazil and would like to go to Uruguay, Argentina, Paraguay and return to Brazil.

I can stay 90 days a year in Brazil, but I am wondering if I am allowed to enter the country multiple times.

Is that possible?

Comment: Which EU country are you a citizen of?  Some EU countries have bilateral visa agreements that may supersede the general EU-Brazil agreement.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, this is allowed for EU passport holders depending on how long you spend outside of Brazil in between visits, and how long your visits last.

**Exception**: this regulation does not apply to citizens of Croatia, Portugal, Poland, United Kingdom and Ireland.

As seen on their [website](http://berlim.itamaraty.gov.br/en-us/entry_regulations_and_terms_of_stay.xml) Brazil allows:

> The 90-day period begins on the date of first entry and will be
> counted continuously; during these 90 days, however, a multiple entry
> and exit is permitted (multiple entrance);
>
> After expiry of the
> permitted 90 days, Brazil must be left definitively; only after 90
> days of stay outside Brazil, re-entry is permitted again; According to
> this regulation, the total duration of stay may NOT exceed 90 days
> within a period of 6 months

So, depending on how long you plan to spend outside of Brazil, you will either be able to renter on the same 90 day count after spending 90 days away, or if you spent more than 90 days the first time only after 6 months away, your count will reset and you will be able to enter on a new 90 days.