# Can visa-free stay in Brazil be extended to 180 days?

Tags: visas, visa-free-entry, multiple-entry, brazil, visa-extensions

I’m confused about my stay in Brazil. I have a Romanian passport (part of the European Union), and I don’t need a visa if I want to stay in Brazil up to 90 days.

I understood that the 90 days are counted continuously from the day I arrived.

If I arrived in Brazil on 1st of September, am I allowed to stay until 29th of November (90 days) no matter if I leave the country and renter in the meantime?

If that’s the case, if I want to stay more, is it possible to request 90 days more for a visa-free stay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend it, at the discretion of the police.

From [Brazil Gringo](http://braziliangringo.com/tourist-visa-brazil/#How_to_Extend_Your_Stayin_Brazil):

> Requests to extend your tourist visa for an additional 90 days must be
>   made at the local Federal Police office. A complete list of Policia
>   Federal locations is found at the bottom of this post.
>
> It’s very important that you extend your stay before the initial 90
>   allotment has run out. If you stay 91 days and go to the Federal
>   Police expecting to get an extension the Federal Police may give you a
>   paper telling you that you have 7 days to leave the country instead.
>
> You will need the following documents:
>
> A filled out visa extension request form. [Found here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/BrazilianGringo/visa+extension.docx).
>
> A printed bank
>   statement or valid credit card to prove you will have sufficient money
>   to spend another 90 days in the country; the bank statement has to be
>   in your name.
>
> Proof of outbound travel. For simplicity’s sake, bring
>   an airline ticket. A bus ticket will probably work without too much
>   explaining. Having none of this, but having hotel bookings in a
>   neighboring country may work with a bit of explaining done in your
>   best Portuguese.
>
> Your passport with the entrance stamp to Brazil.
>
> Your
>   tourist card (Cartão de Entrada), issued when entering Brazil.
>
> Receipt
>   of payment of visa fee. To do this you’ll first need to fill out this
>   online form (updated July 2018) and print out a receipt which you can
>   pay at any bank. On the web form under Unidade Arrecadadora choose the
>   city you’ll be submitting your request to. If you’re in a capital city
>   you’ll choose Superintendincia regional no estado de [whatever state
>   you’re in]. For codigo de receita STN use 140090, being the code for
>   visa extentions. Then click ‘gerar guia,’ print out the form and pay
>   the R$67 fee at the bank. Bring the receipt with you when you submit
>   your visa application. Note that the website doesn’t always work with
>   all browsers, so if it does something funny for you then try in a
>   different browser.

Comment: I do NOT have a “tourist visa”. I’m using my passport and my stay is visa-free. I’m not sure if that means I have a a tourist visa, but I’m afraid it probably does not mean that...

Comment: If you received a time period of 90 days, that's usually a tourist visa on arrival....

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. I will try calling them tomorrow and see what they say. Will return with some info here. :)

Comment: I talked to Policia Federal and they told me I can _easily_ extend my stay to 180, and I can go in the last 30 days of my first 90 day span (particularly, in Porto Alegre, they said I can go even two days before the first 90 days will expire, but that may differ from one office to another).

Comment: @IonicăBizău fantastic!

Comment: An update: I went personally to an office of the Policia Federal — and the things are like this: with a Romanian passport I can *not* extend my stay in Brazil, however, the days outside of Brazil are not counted continually. I can stay in Brazil 90 days each 6 months. However, this applies to the Romanian passport, for other countries it could be different. It would be good to update the answer.

Comment: And I don't think the Turist Visa is the stamp on my passport. Instead it's another document travelers have to request before entering the country. I think the article mentioned in the answer applies primarily to the USA citizens...

Answer (score 1):

From this question:

- [Is there any restriction in entering the South American countries multiple times in one year?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/148065/is-there-any-restriction-in-entering-the-south-american-countries-multiple-times/148068#148068)

> > > As seen on their [website](http://berlim.itamaraty.gov.br/en-us/entry_regulations_and_terms_of_stay.xml) Brazil allows:
> >
> > The 90-day period begins on the date of first entry and will be
> >     counted continuously; during these 90 days, however, a multiple entry
> >     and exit is permitted (multiple entrance)

To extend your stay afterwards, you will need to apply for a visa.